# How to write an Update Statement to update multiple columns where columns are in rows in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

In my scenario I have a table where column names are stored in rows. Using this table columns and data I have to update another table column values. Below are my tables:

Table:Product

| ProductName | ProductCount | InventoryId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bicycles | 100 | 101 |
| Baby Products | 200 | 101 |
| Books | 30 | 101 |

Table: Inventory

| InventoryId | Bicycles | BabyProducts | Books |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 50 | 20 | 30 |

--------Update Statement--------

```
UPDATE Inventory
SET I.Bicycles = P.ProductCount
FROM Inventory I
JOIN Product P ON I.inventoryid = P.inventoryid
WHERE P.ProductName='Bicycles'
```

Instead of writing multiple update statements how to use one single query to update multiple columns?

Comment: please tag you database system they all differ

Comment: This is the kind of issue you encounter when you design your tables badly. Have you considered taking a database design tutorial or buying a book to learn how to do things properly, so that you can avoid these kinds of issues?

Comment: You need to stop and rethink your design, this is simply not how you should implement it and it is unsustainable. Your column represents a category and this should be a single column in your product table. If you had 100 categories you would not want 100 columns.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

UPDATE Inventory
SET I.Bicycles = P.ProductCount,
I.another field= P.anotherfield,
FROM Inventory I
JOIN Product P ON I.inventoryid = P.inventoryid
WHERE P.ProductName='Bicycles'

as many times as necessary, separated by commas, inside the set